# Could not find any gems in Docker when i run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

When i start to run a Rails console in my docker container i got the error `Could not find ..... in locally installed gems` with the list of all gems

`rails s` or `rails routes` work fine and i don't got errors when i build

bundle install change nothing

The one way i found to fix it is with `docker-compose run web bundle install --binstubs`

I doesnt find same problems here with all gems bundle install issue and i would like know what is wrong in my Docker files

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Ruby 2.5.0 image as the parent image
FROM ruby:2.5.0-slim

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y \
    # Needed for certain gems
    build-essential \
    shared-mime-info \
    # Needed for postgres gem
    libpq-dev \
    # Needed for mysql
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    # Needed for redis
    libssl-dev \
    # Needed for elastic search
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    # Needed for foreman
    procps

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into the image and install gems
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.3.26
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Copy the rest of the application code into the image
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 for the Rails app to listen on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Rails app with Puma
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app_api_dev
      MYSQL_USER: app_api
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app_api
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  redis:
    image: redis
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_USERNAME: app_api
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: app_api
      DATABASE_NAME: app_api_dev
```

Comment: Are the installed gems in the `/app/vendor` directory in the container?  Since your `volumes:` hide everything in `/app`, that block also would hide that directory.  You don't need that `volumes:` block (the application code is correctly `COPY`ed into the image) and deleting it might help.

Comment: I tried to check vendor directory with the bash i didnt see the gems and when i delete volumes: block of web it doesn't change @DavidMaze

Comment: Include the logs from building the images, include the output of `gem info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer doesn't make much sense:

1. `--binstubs` does not install gems; it generates stubs in `bin/` from the gems that are already installed as part of the bundle, allowing them to be invoked without prefixing the commands with `bundle exec`.
2. Splitting the command into two separate `RUN` statements that run each command exactly the same as before has no impact on the outcome of the commands being run, it just results in two separate Docker layers which will increase the overall size of the Docker image for no reason.

There are a few actual issues that I think you're seeing. First is that you're:

1. Setting `WORKDIR` to `/app` in your container
2. Using `COPY . .` to copy the contents of your app into `/app`
3. Configuring Docker Compose to mount `.` into your Docker container at `/app`

The result is that step 2 may as well not be happening at all; the files that you copied into `/app` are ignored and Docker Compose instead reads directly from your local computer's filesystem. This is probably not the intended behavior if you're expecting to build a Docker image that contains your app.

This can be especially problematic if you're using a `.dockerignore` file and expect that certain files and folders are not being copied into the image; volumes don't respect `.dockerignore` and the *entire* directory is available at `/app`.

And again this can be problematic if you're using `bundle config` options like `BUNDLE_PATH` and `BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH` that you don't expect to be loaded into your app. You might be expecting gems to be installed to and read from locations within your Docker image's system paths but if `bundle config` options you don't expect to have in place are pointing to a local path like `vendor/bundle` and `vendor/cache` then mounting the volume to the local path is going to use these pre-existing paths on your local system, not what's in the image.

The second issue is that you're not running commands with `bundle exec`. You don't make it clear how you're attempting to run `rails console` or `rails server` or `rails routes` but these commands need to be prefixed with `bundle exec`, e.g., `bundle exec rails console`. For example, if you've already run `docker compose up` and the server is running:

```bash
docker exec -it web bash
```

And then when you're in your container:

```bash
cd /app
bundle exec rails console
```

If you want to use binstubs instead then *before* you create your Docker image you need to run `bundle binstubs --all` on your local computer to create the stubs in `bin/`, then to invoke those commands using the binstubs you need to run them with their relative path included, e.g.:

```bash
bin/rails console
bin/rails server
bin/rails routes
```

You would need to do this anywhere that you would otherwise run `bundle exec rails ...`.

Finally, attempting to run them with just `rails console` or `rails server` is likely not going to work because it requires the Docker image itself to have those gems installed globally, and those global versions may not match your bundled versions. If you just run `rails <something>` then what happens is the system will look in `$PATH` to attempt to find a binary named `rails` -- it does not automagically find the version of Rails that you have defined in `Gemfile.lock` and does not automagically find the binary installed by `bundle install`. It just finds the first responsive binary which may or may not know about your bundled application and its dependencies. Always specify the command with either `bundle exec rails ...` or `bin/rails ...`.